# Analyzing Variances between AWS Dashboard Display and Cost Explorer SDK Calculations

Tags: amazon-web-services, sdk, cost-management, aws-cost-explorer

There is a slight difference between the cost shown in the AWS dashboard and the cost obtained when calculating the monthly cost through the AWS cost explorer SDK. What could be the reason for that?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LgaRE.png)

| Service | Cost Explorer SDK ($) | AWS Dashboard ($) |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Neptune | 70.0700546215 | 72.40 |
| EC2-Instance | 71.4260524572 | 71.43 |
| EC2-Other | 57.7973261169 | 60.28 |
| VPC | 11.2601180897 | 11.98 |
| S3 | 6.7667165439 | 6.99 |
| Elastic Load Balancing | 5.7825053328 | 6.32 |
| Key Management Service | 0.977930436 | 1.04 |
| Data Pipeline | 0.96774192 | 1.00 |
| CloudWatch | 0.2595207752 | 0.31 |